# How can i link the vector elements to a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I need help in the class design workflow with the following functionality.

I have a class with the name of Stage the stage has a variable of class Director as vector and i would want to point to these data elements of the vector from another class Channel.

```
class Stage
{
private:
    int time;
    std::vector<Director> directors;
public:
    Stage()
    { }
    void AddDirector(Director director)
    {
        directors.push_back(director);
    }    
    Director* GetDirector(int index)
    {
        return &directors[index];
    }    
    void DeleteDirector(std::string dirName)
    {
        // remove the director from the vector which matches the name of the input string
    } 
};
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class Director
{
private:
    int time;
    std::string stdstrDirName;
public:
    Director()
    { }
    std::string GetName()
    {
        return stdstrDirName;
    }
    void SetName(std::string name)
    {
        stdstrDirName = name;
    }

   // GetTime and SetTime

};




 class Channel
{
private:
    int time;
    std::string stdstrChannelName;
    Director* dir;
public:
    Channel()
    { }
    std::string GetName()
    {
        return stdstrChannelName;
    }
    void SetName(std::string name)
    {
        stdstrChannelName = name;
    }

    std::string  GetDirectorName()
    {
        dir->GetName();
    }

    void SetDirector(Director* director)
    {
        dir = director;
    }

};
```

This is how i would point them.

```
int main()
{
    Stage stage;  // Create Stage Object
    Director d1, d2, d3; // Create Director Objects
    Channel channel;
    d1.SetName("D1"); d2.SetName("D2"); d3.SetName("D3");
    stage.AddDirector(d1); stage.AddDirector(d2); stage.AddDirector(d3);
    channel.SetDirector(stage.GetDirector(1)); // Link Director to Channel
}
```

This approach has a drawback whenever the vector gets resize  the pointers in the Channel will not hold reference to their valid object.

I  need help in what should be the design of the class structure ?

Comment: You have an error of software engineering here. Does it makes sense for either the `Stage` or the `Channel` to own the director? Can a channel exist without its director? Can a director exist without its channel? What should happen to a channel if its director is removed from the director container? Take a moment to draw out what these relationships should be and that might help inform the design better.

Comment: @John i want the Stage to own the director and channel to point towards the director  whenever i delete a director i will delete all the channels associated with that director , i have not shown that in the code as this is not the problem i am facing.

Comment: Instead of a vector of Directors you could hold all Directors in a map, then each Channel would have the associated key of its own Director.

Comment: Or the vector of `Director`s could how `std::unique_ptr<Director>`s instead. Then the ptr held by each `Channel` isn't subject to change.

Comment: @John even if i resize the vector in the Stage ?

Comment: but that would delete the director if i delete the Channel ?

Comment: What if your elements move?

Comment: If the `vector` of `unique_ptr` is resized, the pointers are moved to the newly constructed `unique_ptr`s. If you want to delete the `Director` when you delete the `Channel` you'll have to explicitly remove the `unique_ptr` from the `vector`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo apologies i am not able to understand your comment

Comment: @John thank you now using unique ptr it works fine if you want to post an answer please do that.

Comment: @Summit John expressed the same concerns I tried to express with my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your vector could store pointers to the Director objects rather than the objects themselves. That way, resizes will not affect existing pointers.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of using reference(&) instead of pointers?

Comment: This would not help. If a pointer to an object is invalidated, then a reference to that object would also be invalidated.